# How to show images using Play framework and Scala in the view page

Tags: scala, playframework

Using the Play framework, I'm trying to show the image `friend_request.png` in the view page.

This is my code but the image is not showing:

```
<img src=@("images/friend_request.png") width="28" height="22" />
```

Comment: Do you have the images in `public/images`?

Answer (score 11):

I assume you want to include a static image, and since you're talking about Scala, I assume you're using Play Framework 2.

The appropriate place of the image in the standard project layout should be `public/images/friend_request.png`.
You can then refer to the image:

```
<img src="@routes.Assets.at("images/friend_request.png")" width="28" height="22" />
```

For more information on assets (caching time, etc.), please refer to the [Play Framework documentation](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.0/Assets).

Comment: thanx..for the answr.. And another question
 the image path from database and show in view page is it possible

Comment: @user2400597 You want to display images you stored in a database? Just create a controller (which reads the data and returns it; mind the correct mime type) and add a route to it. Then embed them using the reverse router again (e.g. `@routes.Images.display`).

Answer (score 4):

[Skyr's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16831912/how-to-show-images-using-play-framework-and-scala-in-the-view-page/31547339#16833889) doesnt' work for my version of Play (2.4.2). Using it yields the following compilation error:

> value **at** is not a member of controllers.ReverseAssets

After consulting the [documentation](https://playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/Assets), this works for me:

```
<img src="@routes.Assets.versioned("images/yourImage.png")">
```

where `yourImage.png` is in `public/images`.

---

If you want to speed up page loading via caching and compressing your images (and all the other assets of your web app), try this:

Make sure that your `plugins.sbt` contains these entries:

```
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-rjs" % "1.0.7")
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-digest" % "1.1.0")
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-gzip" % "1.0.0")
```

Then, in your `build.sbt`, add this:

```
// Apply RequireJS optimizations, create a checksum, and zip each asset
pipelineStages := Seq(rjs, digest, gzip)
```